# How do I delete files from dir plus db

Tags: php, checkbox, delete-row, unlink

So this is how I tried an put them together
But deleting the file in dir needs a value in the name of checkbox and deleting the row in db doesn't...

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['checkbox'])){       

    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){
    $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM media WHERE id='$del_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    }
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value){
    $name = $key;
    list($dir, $file_name_type) = explode("/",$name);   // get actual file name
    $actual_name = $file_name_type;
    list($actual_name,$type) = explode(".",$file_name_type);
if(unlink($key) && $result){
    $_SESSION["message"]="Datei <b style=\"color:#005577\"> &nbsp; ".$actual_name."</b>  &nbsp; wurde erfolgreich gel&ouml;scht :)";
    header ("Location: media.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION["message"]="Datei <b style=\"color:#005577\"> &nbsp; ".$actual_name."</b>  &nbsp; konnte nicht gel&ouml;scht werden.";}
    header ("Location: media.php");
    }
}
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM media ORDER BY date DESC");
confirm_query($result);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $post_date = new DateTime($row["date"]);

echo "
    <tr>
        <td><input name=\"checkbox[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=" .$row['id']. ">
        <td><a class=\"image\" href=" .$row['path']. " rel=\"lightbox\"><img src=" .$row["path"]. " height=\"50\"></a></td>
        <td class=\"title\">" .$row['file_name']. "</td>
        <td class=\"date\">".strftime("%e. %b, '%g", $post_date->getTimestamp())."</td>
    </tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</form>
```

Cheers Chris

Comment: How did you put them together? Because both your scripts contain a redirect (header()), which will stop the rest of the code to execute.

Comment: @MalcolmKindermans Script execution goes on upon header redirect.

Comment: Come on, if you cannot inteligently merge these 2 funtions into one sensible function then you are just pasting together snippets of code you dont understand. **This is not WeDoYourWorkForFree.COM** At least show one of your attempts, then we can comment and suggest

Comment: @MalcolmKindermans Thats why you should follow all `header()` calls with an `exit;` You have decided you should be on another page so go to another page and get out of Dodge.

Comment: @DanFromGermany thnx :) learning something while helping others :P Riggs, sorry, can only mention one person in a post. But your comment was not forgotten :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve my problem thanx

```
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM media WHERE path='$key'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $name = $key;
    list($dir, $file_name_type) = explode("/",$name);   // get actual file name
    $actual_name = $file_name_type;
    list($actual_name,$type) = explode(".",$file_name_type);
if(unlink($key) && $result){
    $_SESSION["message"]="Datei <b style=\"color:#005577\"> &nbsp; ".$actual_name."</b>  &nbsp; wurde erfolgreich gel&ouml;scht :)";
    header ("Location: media.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION["message"]="Datei <b style=\"color:#005577\"> &nbsp; ".$actual_name."</b>  &nbsp; konnte nicht gel&ouml;scht werden.";}
    header ("Location: media.php");
    }
}
```

Seems to work nicely like this thanx

Cheers Chris